# How to configure seed node systems in akka

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, typesafe

This might a bit of a stupid question, but I have been at it for days.
I went through the akka documentation for clusters. There it mentions that I'd have to list the seed node IP address in the application.conf. But the question I have I how do I set up the seed node. I have a laptop that I write code on, I want it to use the JVM on another machine as well. What do I configure here?

I'm really really new to this, please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just because you did not mention it, this is only needed for Akka Cluster.

For development use `localhost` as seed node. Pick one of the nodes that you will always use when working locally:

```
akka {
  remote.netty.tcp {
    hostname = localhost
    port = 2551
  }
  cluster.seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://esc@localhost:2551"]
}
```

Just ensure that you are using this one application's port as seed node port.

Any subsequent nodes that should then join this cluster locally would need a config like this:

```
akka {
  remote.netty.tcp {
    hostname = localhost
    port = 0 # automatically select; alternatively choose fixed port different from 2551
  }
  cluster.seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://esc@localhost:2551"]
}
```

This will then allow you to run multiple Akka applications locally.

You could also have an extra application acting as seed node (then running with two instances later in production). This would just start the actor system and then wait for other nodes to join. We did this a while ago, but I'm not too sure that it's a nice idea. Maybe look at [Akka Management's Cluster Bootstrap](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/akka-management/current/bootstrap/index.html).

Maybe also for clarification, as there is so much confusion with it based on my experience: The seed nodes do not necessarily act as Leader in the cluster. They (because of them being configured for the other nodes) just allow other nodes (that can have dynamically assigned IPs/hostnames) to discover each other. See also [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/common/cluster.html#leader).